# Scraping dropdown lists with Scrapy

Tags: python, loops, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a dropdown list that has the following source code format using Scrapy.

```
 - ul>
    - li>
      - a> text=header_1
      - nested_ul>
        - nested_li> value_1
    - li>
      - a> text=header_2
      - nested_ul>
        - nested_li> value_2
        - nested_li> value_3
        - nested_li> value_4
    - li>
      - a> text=header_3
      - nested_ul>
        - nested_li> value_5
        - nested_li> value_6
```

I am able to scrape all the headers to one list and all the values to one list, however I am unsure how to scrape the values nested, as seen below. My problem is related to python syntax rather than scraping the data, which is why I didn't include classes/ids for lists. I appreciate the help.

```
# Desired Output
headers_list = [h1, h2, h3]
value_list = [[v1], [v2,v3,v4], [v5,v6]]
```

Comment: anyone have suggestions? I believe it is some form of a for loop, but I can't figure it out. I just need the value list nested when being scraped instead of  one list with all values.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the selector of `<li>` tag and use it to get the data from there.

```
headers_list = list()
value_list = list()
for li in response.xpath('//li'):
    headers_list.append(li.xpath('./a/text()').get())
    value_list.append(li.xpath('./ul/li/text()').getall())
```